# Проблема с ggplot + openstreetmap

Tags: r

Пытаюсь наложить точки на карту:

```
library(OpenStreetMap)
library(ggplot2)
map <- openmap(c(52.843, 20.962), c(43.644, 41.396), type='osm')               

data <- data.frame(lat= 51, lon=35, prsf=10)

autoplot(map)+ geom_point(data=data, aes(lon, lat, size=prsf))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получаю следующее. Уже все перепробовал.
Не подскажете, где проблема?

Comment: проблема в проекции и единицах измерения  
Общая рекомендация: смотрите в сторону {sf} {mapview}  
https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/articles/sf5.html